# Run the code inside of string Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I have a variable (string) in Javascript, in which you for example have this text:

```
"document.getElementById('tekst').innerHTML = 'Probeer opnieuw!';"
```

I got this variable using Ajax and PHP, but that is not where my (possibly very easy) question is about.

Say I want to use this code as code itself, not as a string, so instead of this being a string I would like the code inside of it to be executed.

How can I possibly do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do this. [It's a security nightmare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/86580/367865).

If you really must do this, use [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) as in:

```
eval("document.getElementById('tekst').innerHTML = 'Probeer opnieuw!';");
```

---

Considering your example and explanation, I suspect that you are retrieving a url whose contents consist entirely of javascript. The problem you've run across is that the method you are using to retrieve that url gives you a string containing that javascript. I believe that it's intended for you to instead use a `<script>` element to load that code. To do so dynamically:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "url/to/your/javascript";
document.getElementByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) method. But don't do it if you don't have to. And if you *do* have to, make sure you know what you're doing.

```
eval("document.getElementById('tekst').innerHTML = 'Probeer opnieuw!';")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative to using `eval()` :

```
var stringContainingJavascript = "document.getElementById('tekst').innerHTML = 'Probeer opnieuw!';"

var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

var paragraph = document.createElement('p');
paragraph.id = 'tekst';
body.appendChild(paragraph);

var script = document.createElement('script');
var scriptText = document.createTextNode(stringContainingJavascript);
script.appendChild(scriptText);
body.appendChild(script);
```

The script above creates a `<p>` element and gives it `id="tekst"`, before appending the `<p>` to the `<body>` of the document.

The same script then creates a `<script>` element and appends the string to it, before appending the `<script>` to the `<body>` of the document.